# How to configure PWM on STM32F429I-Discovery Board

Tags: led, pwm, stm32, embedded, timer

Currently I have some difficulties on the Discovery Board STM32F429I to control the on-board LEDs via PWM. According to the data sheet of the Discovery Board the LEDs are located on pin 13 and pin 14 (PG13 & PG14).

According to my research, it is possible to solve the PWM control with the on-board Timer to dim the LEDs. In the data sheet of the MCU, I don't see any timer assignments as an alternative function to generate the PWM signal at the LED. Enclosed is the mapping table from the data sheet of the MCU:

[image: Alternative Function Mapping STM32F429I Disco]

Is there no "elegant" possibility to control the on-board LED via PWM?

Which alternative ways exist to control the brightness via PWM of the on-board LED?

---

Thank you very much.

- [Link to the STM32F429I-Discovery Board user manual:](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/6b/25/05/23/a9/45/4d/6a/DM00093903.pdf/files/DM00093903.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00093903.pdf)
- [Link to STM32F429 MCU data sheet:](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00071990.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The hardware solution**

Find two suitable timer output pins (check the *STM32 pin description versus board functions* table in the user manual of the board), and connect them with jumper wires to PG13 and PG14 on the board headers.

[image]

Then proceed to configuring the PWM outputs on the selected pins. Always set PG13 and PG14 as inputs, otherwise the MCU might be damaged.

**The software solution**

If your program has a functioning SysTick interrupt handler, you can toggle the pins in the handler function. If you don't want the LEDs to visibly flicker, you'd need at least 20 Hz frequency. With a SysTick frequency of 1 kHz, 51 distinct output levels are possible, 0% to 100% in 2% steps.

```
volatile int led1_level; // set this variable to control the duty cycle in 2% steps
void dim_leds() { // call this function from SysTick_Handler()
  static int cnt;
  cnt = (cnt + 1) % 50;
  if(cnt < led1_level)
    GPIOG->BSRR = 1 << 13;
  else
    GPIOG->BSRR = 1 << (13 + 16);
}
```

Controlling PG14 is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much for the workaround. In fact, I noticed now that the pins PG13 and PG14 are also available for the LEDS as well as for the outside. Nevertheless, I have a question whether the onboard LED lights up at all if I define it as an input. Are these connected in such a way that they also light up as input? I currently prefer the software method with the SysTick_Handler.

Comment: The LED would be connected to two pins at the same time. One of them, the timer output is driving the LED. The other one is a high impedance input, as if it were not there. Find the LED in the schematics at the end of the board user manual. Draw a connection to the timer output pin, parallel to `PG13`. Now scratch the connection to `PG13`, and draw a connection to GND through a 1MΩ resistor, it'd be the substitute for the input pin. What do you think now, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PG13 & PG14 can't be connected to a timer module. You can check it in CubeMX by clicking on those pins (as @muyustan has mentioned), you will not see any timer in the drop-down list. This can also be confirmed from the datasheet: The pin listing table on page 68 doesn't mention a timer connection for those pins. And finally, as you have already figured out, there is no such an option in the alternate function table.

However, I can think of a dirty hack to dim those LEDs connected to PG13 & PG14.

PG13 can be used as SPI6_SCK. So if you use SPI6 to send (or receive) dummy bytes continuously, you can obtain 50 % duty cycle on that pin. Unfortunately, that is all you can do for PG13 other than 0 % and 100 %.

The situation is better for PG14. You have 2 options: USART6_TX and SPI6_MOSI. You can send specific bit trains to obtain some duty cycle values, like sending 0b00000011 for 25 % duty cycle. If you can spare a DMA in circular mode, it can retrieve this byte from your dummy duty register and feed the SPI as needed.

I would go for the SPI option. In that case, you can control both PG13 & PG14 with SPI6. To set PG13 to 100 % or 0 %, you need to change MODER and revert it back to GPIO output mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. The idea with the UART (for PG14) to generate a PWM signal is indeed very clever. Too bad that there is no elegant alternative.